# Cant render the array values using .map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this:

```
var Astronomy = React.createClass({
getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {meteo : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('meteo')).data};
},
render: function() {
    return (
    <div className="temps">
    {this.props.meteo.weather.map(function(d, i) {return
        <div className="waqt">
            <div className="temps">
                <div className="raise">
                    <div className="sunraise"><i className="riz">{this.props.meteo.weather[i]["astronomy"][0]["sunrise"]}</i></div>
                    <div className="sunset"><i className="riz">{this.props.meteo.weather[i]["astronomy"][0]["sunset"]}</i></div>
                </div>
                <div className="set">
                    <div className="moonraise"><i className="riz">{this.props.meteo.weather[i]["astronomy"][0]["moonrise"]}</i></div>
                    <div className="moonset"><i className="riz">{this.props.meteo.weather[i]["astronomy"][0]["moonset"]}</i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    )}
    </div>
    );
},
componentDidMount: function() {
return console.log(this.props.meteo.weather[0]["astronomy"][0]["sunrise"]);
},
});
```

But I get an empty result ! even the console gives what I expect `06:19 AM`, and debugging it using chrome extension, I see that the array stayed as it is like in the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: if someone came here, React warns when you dont use a key, add this `<div className="waqt" key={index}>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript will insert a semicolon after `return` if it is followed by a line break. I.e.

```
function foo() {
  return
  42
}
```

is the same as

```
function foo() {
  return;
  42
}
```

i.e. the last line will never be evaluated and `undefined` will be returned.

The return value always has to be or start at the same line as the `return` statement:

```
return (
  <div>...</div>
);
```

---

Also there is no need to access the data as `this.props.meteo.weather[i]`. That value is already passed to the callback as `d`, so you can just do `d.astronomy[0].sunrise`. Learn more about `.map` in the [**MDN documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: wonerful! not only worked, but I got a wonderful course about `map` and about `the evil semicolon`, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

```
var Astronomy = React.createClass({
getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {meteo : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('meteo')).data};
},
render: function() {
    return (
    <div className="temps">
    {this.props.meteo.weather.map(function(d, i) {
    return <div className="waqt">
            <div className="temps">
                <div className="raise">
                    <div className="sunraise"><i className="riz">{this.props.meteo.weather[i]["astronomy"][0]["sunrise"]}</i></div>
                    <div className="sunset"><i className="riz">{this.props.meteo.weather[i]["astronomy"][0]["sunset"]}</i></div>
                </div>
                <div className="set">
                    <div className="moonraise"><i className="riz">{this.props.meteo.weather[i]["astronomy"][0]["moonrise"]}</i></div>
                    <div className="moonset"><i className="riz">{this.props.meteo.weather[i]["astronomy"][0]["moonset"]}</i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    },this )}
    </div>
    );
},
componentDidMount: function() {
return console.log(this.props.meteo.weather[0]["astronomy"][0]["sunrise"]);
},
});
```

`this` has change in the `map` function,your can appoint it by the second argument,or use `()=>`  ES6 arrow function.

Comment: but why it works even without `this` ?
Edit: adding `this`, makes it in an inifinte loop that crashes the browser (Chrome)

Comment: since i dont have the complete code , i cant run it in your situation. here is my demo https://jsfiddle.net/znd4ose3/1/

Comment: can you edit the answer and explain the role of this, because it is unclear, since it worked without, but in this example when i remove it, it doesent work.

Comment: map is called by `this.props.meteo.weather`,so , in the function ,`this` is `this.props.meteo.weather`

Comment: ah, so using the `d` as argument did the same trick, thank you again!